# How feasible is Laser Plasma Acceleration for the post-LHC world?

Tags: accelerator-physics

I was wondering how feasible Laser Plasma Acceleration for the post-LHC world is. It seems very promising.

Comment: This is [one of several related techniques often lumped together as "wakefield accelration"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_acceleration#Comparison_with_RF_Acceleration), and people are working on it. How does the wikipedia article fail to enlighten you?

Comment: Welcome to physis.sx! Your question seems a little too broard and it resambles more an invitation to discuss the theme than a question.Try to go to the point.

Comment: You might be interested in having a look at my answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119626/

Answer (score 1):

While the technology is promising, we are still very far from being capable of building a machine based on it, especially at the energy frontier.

Indeed ALL the existing post-LHC projects (circular or linear, leptonic or hadronic) are based on conventional radio frequency acceleration.