# Particle accelerators by focused laser beam?

Tags: particle-accelerators

My (layman) estimate is that such accelerators could relatively easily and cheap override the current high-end, multimilliard-$ accelerators. Some years ago I've read some interesting breakthrough in the news, but practically nothing since that.

What is the current focus of the research/development? Is there any obstacle found? What is the current estimate to the practical energy limit of such accelerators?

Comment: Are you thinking of [plasma accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_acceleration)? If so, these are many years (decades?) from seeing action in the field.

Comment: @JohnRennie Practically yes, but my question is focusing on the collider site. For example, the current record is 2GeV with electrons ( http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2013/130611/ncomms2988/full/ncomms2988.html ), which was reached in 2cm... Is there any obstacle before this technology to be a cheap alternative of the current LHC?

Comment: You're basically asking for a review on the status of plasma accelerator design, and that's far too broad to be usefully answered here. I'm sure some determined Googling will find you relevant reviews.

Comment: @JohnRennie No. I only a short answer from the status report from the current situation of the development, and from the current visible practical limit.

Comment: If you go to particle physics conferences (the APS division of particle and fields meeting, say), there are generally accelerator physics sections, and the titles for those section are always intriguing. But the ones I've attended have been (1) mostly over my head and (2) talking about a calculation or the wonderful gradient they achieved for a few microseconds in a test chamber a few tens of centimeters long. They are working hard on this stuff, but it is still in the calculate, prototype, tinker, repeat stage of development.

Comment: @dmckee Thank you! What do you think, is it possible that they will in 10-20 yrs break the record of the actual collider?

Comment: This stuff is like fusion. The optimistic estimates have been "five to ten years" for a couple of decades now. I imagine that it will happen sooner or later, but decline to guess when.

Comment: @dmckee Ok. My estimate is: 2GeV on 2cm means 200000GeV = 200TeV on 2km, if they can maintain the beam on a longterm. I think this is a too promising possibility for a lost closing vote - if you could help the case, please do.

Comment: Peter, I'm with @John. You are asking for a review of a significant and active field of research. As I said, they fill multiple sections of major conferences with this subject every year. You need a review paper, not a SE post.

Comment: @dmckee I am a layman. Maybe a short summary of a review paper + an arxiv link, hadn't been the best answer to a such question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15156/discussion-between-dmckee-and-peter-horvath).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not work directly in the field, so I will probably give an incomplete answer, but to my knowledge there are two major obstacles.

The first consists in keeping the accelerating structure inside the plasma stable. We are not talking about a solid metal radio frequency cavity here, but some charged-fluid nano structures which are very sensitive to a number of perturbations, included the one with themselves.

The second problem is keeping the particle to accelerate within this structures both in the transversal plane (which may come for free as long the plasma bubbles are stable) but also in the longitudinal which is harder since the laser travels the plasma with velocity $<c$ while electrons approach $c$ very rapidly. A different approach consists in using a particle beam instead of a laser beam to excite the plasma, this may sound easier but let me report few lines from the [AWAKE project at CERN](http://awake.web.cern.ch/awake/physics.html):

> The AWAKE experiment intends to use the existing conventional SPS beam to drive a high amplitude wakefield [- in the plasma] which will then accelerate a witness electron beam. The SPS beam is, however, too long to effectively drive a wakefield. The AWAKE experiment will longitudinally micro-bunch the beam into hundreds of far shorter beams using a wakefield initially driven by a short laser pulse. These beams will then be able to resonantly excite a high amplitude wakefield.

The SPS aka Super Proton Synchrotron is a 7km ring (the one at which W and Z bosons where discovered and that now injects protons in the LHC), so not quite a table-top experiment! And it's just an experiment: something to prove the concept and develop some fundamental technology. It will require much more effort to develop something that can be really used.

This technique is promising but very complex and immature. That's why all the  major new projects of any kind of particle-accelerator machines still rely on RF acceleration.

---

A 2 GeV electron beam is already pretty interesting: you can have a nice FEL, or, colliding two of them, a $\tau/$charm factory. These machines cost typically few hundreds millions $, they are not at the energy fronter but can produce plenty of physics and eventually Nobel prizes.

Having such a beam over 2cm is for sure very exciting, but the energy is just one of the beam parameters. How many particles are in a bunch, what is the phase space volume occupied by them, what is the repetition rate achievable, how much power is effectively transferred to the beam? These are the kind of questions that you should ask and whose answers still let you go for RF acceleration.